# Flutter - Unidentified cause for pixel overflow

Tags: android, ios, macos, dart, flutter

I've been trying to transplant some code from [this flutter project](https://github.com/iampawan/CryptoApp) into [into this boilerplate sample](https://github.com/zmqgithub/styled_list) and am running into some pixel overflow issues that I can't seem to fix.

This is the error thrown in the VSCode debug console;

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1514 pos 12:
flutter: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
```

And this is the code I'm using the stimulate the error;

`home_page.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cryptick_nice_ui/data/crypto_data.dart';
import 'package:cryptick_nice_ui/modules/crypto_presenter.dart';
import 'background.dart';
import 'package:cryptick_nice_ui/dependency_injection.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
          primaryColor: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
              ? Colors.grey[100]
              : null),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> implements CryptoListViewContract {
  CryptoListPresenter _presenter;
  List<Crypto> _currencies;
  bool _isLoading;
  final List<MaterialColor> _colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.indigo, Colors.red];





  _HomePageState() {
    _presenter = new CryptoListPresenter(this);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    _presenter.loadCurrencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(".",
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
            letterSpacing: 0.8,
            color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
          )
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF273A48),
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: _isLoading
            ? new Center(
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
            : _cryptoWidget()
      );
  }

    Widget _cryptoWidget() {
    final _width1 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height1 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
    ),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new CustomPaint(
            size: new Size(_width1, _height1),
            painter: new Background(),
          ),
            new Flexible(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _currencies.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final int i = index ~/ 2;
                  final Crypto currency = _currencies[i];
                  final MaterialColor color = _colors[i % _colors.length];
                  if (index.isOdd) {
                    return new Divider();
                  }
                  return _getListItemUi(context, currency, color);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      );
  }



  Widget _getListItemUi(BuildContext context, Crypto currency, MaterialColor color) {
    final _width2 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height2 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    _presenter.loadCurrencies();
    final headerList = new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        EdgeInsets padding = index == 0?const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0):const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0);

        return new Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('Card selected');
            },
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withAlpha(70),
                      offset: const Offset(3.0, 10.0),
                      blurRadius: 15.0)
                ],
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new ExactAssetImage(
                      ''),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
//                                    height: 200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: new Container(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: new Radius.circular(10.0),
                                bottomRight: new Radius.circular(10.0))),
                        height: 30.0,
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text(
                              'hi',
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: _currencies.length,
    );

    final body = new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('cryp'),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){})
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: new Container(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: new Text(
                          'Trending News',
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                      height: 300.0, width: _width2, child: headerList),
                  new Expanded(child:
                  ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                height: 72.0,
                                width: 72.0,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      new BoxShadow(
                                          color:
                                          Colors.black.withAlpha(70),
                                          offset: const Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                          blurRadius: 2.0)
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                        new Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                    image: new DecorationImage(
                                      image: new ExactAssetImage(
                                        "cryptoiconsBlack/"+currency.symbol.toLowerCase()+"@2x.png",
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              new SizedBox(
                                width: 8.0,
                              ),
                              new Expanded(
                                  child: new Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Text(
                                        'My item header',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14.0,
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      new Text(
                                        'Item Subheader goes here\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )),
                              new Icon(
                                Icons.shopping_cart,
                                color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          new Divider(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
      ),
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CustomPaint(
            size: new Size(_width2, _height2),
            painter: new Background(),
          ),
          body,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget _getSubtitleText(String priceUSD, String percentageChange) {
    TextSpan priceTextWidget = new TextSpan(
        text: "\$$priceUSD\n", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black));
    String percentageChangeText = "1 hour: $percentageChange%";
    TextSpan percentageChangeTextWidget;

    if (double.parse(percentageChange) > 0) {
      percentageChangeTextWidget = new TextSpan(
          text: percentageChangeText,
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green));
    } else {
      percentageChangeTextWidget = new TextSpan(
          text: percentageChangeText, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
    }

    return new RichText(
        text: new TextSpan(
            children: [priceTextWidget, percentageChangeTextWidget]));
  }



  @override
  void onLoadCryptoComplete(List<Crypto> items) {
    // TODO: implement onLoadCryptoComplete

    setState(() {
      _currencies = items;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onLoadCryptoError() {
    // TODO: implement onLoadCryptoError
    }
  }
```

And this is the `background.dart` file I'm using to create a grey/white pallet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Background extends CustomPainter{
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement paint
    _drawPentagone(canvas,  size);
  }

  _drawPentagone(Canvas canvas, Size size){
    var path = new Path();
    path.addPolygon([
      new Offset(size.width, size.height/5),
      new Offset(size.width, size.height),
      new Offset(0.0, size.height),
      new Offset(0.0, size.height/2.5),

    ], true);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, new Paint()..color = Colors.white);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return false;
  }

}
```

This is what I get in simulator, at the bottom it says `BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 100 PIXELS`

[image: Pixel Overflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making your background widget as large as the screen:

```
final _width1 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final _height1 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

// ...

new CustomPaint(
  size: new Size(_width1, _height1),
  painter: new Background(),
),
```

The `AppBar` at the top probably takes 100 pixels of space, and `_cryptoWidget()` is only uses the space below the `AppBar`-

You don't need `MediaQuery` to create a screen-filling widget, just use a `Container` without any dimensions.

it's also strange that your background widget is wrapped in a `Column` with another `Flexible` below. If the background is screen-filling, how would the `Flexible` fit below?

Are you trying to create a scrollable view? Or do you want to draw the background widget behind the content?

Comment: This looks great. I’d like to just draw the background widget behind the content, and I plan to add a horizontal listView at the top as shown in the boilerplate I’m using, linked in original question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to draw the background behind the content, the content must be a child of `CustomPaint`.

Comment: Okay, I’m sure this all works but I’ll try it in the morning. (23:23) in my country for reference

Comment: Okay this is looking great, thanks for the help. I think I'm going to use `new CustomPaint(
            size: new Size(_width, _height),
            painter: new Background(),
            child: _cryptoWidget()
          ),`

Comment: I think you don't need the `size`

Comment: Yeah I’ve tried it without size and it works fine, I’ll edit the comment soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and inside Scaffold whatever you want can add

```
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          return new Container(
            child: new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new CustomPaint(
                  painter: new Background(),
                  size: new Size(width, height),
                ),
                new Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                      title: new Text("Custom Background"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    body: new Center(
                      child: new Text("Hello how are You? :)"),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
```